# Undefined method 'paginate' with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

When I attempt to include `<%= paginate @coins %>` in the view like this,

```
<div id="coin-index">
  <h1>All Coins</h1>
  <ul class="coins">
    <% @coins = @coins.sort_by &:currency_name %>
    <%= paginate @coins %>
    <% @coins.each do |coin| %>
      <ul><%= link_to coin.currency_name, :action => 'show', :id => coin %></ul>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I get an error saying "undefined method `paginate`". The gem is installed properly.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try to restart the server :)

Comment: Did that too. Still isn't working.

Comment: Could you show me action `index` in `CoinsController`?

Comment: def index
       
        @coins = Coin.order(:currency_name).page params[:page]
    end

Comment: In `rails console`, please using: `Kaminari::Helpers::HelperMethods.instance_methods`. Do you see `paginate` in the return list?

Comment: Yes. It returns: => [:link_to_prev_page,
 :link_to_next_page,
 :path_to_next_page,
 :page_entries_info,
 :rel_next_prev_link_tags,
 :paginate,
 :link_to_previous_page,
 :path_to_prev_page]

Comment: I don't use Kaminari but as I remember, we need to involve paginate method for variable in controller first so that View understands this method.

Comment: What happens when you put `<% require "kaminari" %>` right above the paginate?

Comment: can you please also mention you controller action code?